# Kernel upgrade breaks NVIDIA. Am I stuck with the same kernel forever?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

I switched to Ubuntu ~3 months ago and it is an incredible way to interact with a computer.  I ran into a snag last night after a restart.  I fixed the issue, but it left me with some questions.

Problem:
After restart my screen resolution dropped from `1920x1080` to `800x600` and neither cinnamon nor unity would initialize.  Running the following:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

showed:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760 OEM] (rev a1)
```

But it obviously wasn’t being used for either video or sound.  After some digging, I found that a recent kernel update had taken effect at restart and it wasn’t playing nicely with my NVIDIA graphics card and/or drivers.

Solution:
Restarting Ubuntu using the previous kernel version fixed the problem.  I edited `/etc/default/grub` and ran `grub-update` to default to the previous kernel version and this works.  But now I am worried about the long-term outlook for my machine.

Questions:

1. Should I try reinstalling my NVIDIA drivers?  They were a giant pain to install the first time around.  They are still present on the system so I don’t know if reinstalling them with the new kernel in place would make any difference and I don’t really feel like spending half a day working on a project that appears to have little chance of success.
2. Should I file a bug report with Ubuntu?  Or maybe on the git repository for the kernel?  Is this a bug, or is this kind of thing par for the course when running third party drivers?
3. Most importantly am I now stuck with the Linux 3.16.0-41-generic kernel for the rest of eternity?  Is it likely that this problem will be resolved in 3.16.0-45 or will I just be running on an old kernel until I get a new machine.  My graphics card is not old so I would be surprised if it is no longer supported.  And running an outdated kernel smells like a security risk.  What’s the deal?

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia drivers and where did you get them? Using the "Software Updater" ,"Additional drivers" tab and selecting Nvidia-current should result in an installation which updates with each new kernel. Grabbing a download from a random place, and you will probably need to reinstall yourself each kernel update.

Comment: The generic drivers led to poor performance.  The screen looked jerky whenever there was motion.  So I downloaded and installed drivers suggested for my card from NVidia's site.  I had to boot into the command line without a desktop and I had to run some commands to turn off the Xwindows environment.  I actually don't remember all of the steps but I remember it was a bit painful.  I am sad to hear that I might have to go through that again with every kernel upgrade.

Comment: What exact nvidia driver.version did you get from Nvidia?  What exact version does the nvidia-current install?  What exact version does the nvidia-current-updates install?  Did you check that you are acutally runing the nvidia driver with lsmod?  Which generic driver are you talking about, nouveau or vga?

Comment: Looks like I installed NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-349.16.  I am now looking at installing NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.21 which appears to be the latest greates Nvidia recommendation for my graphics card.  I assumed that when I first installed Ubuntu 14.04 it came with some generic drivers that recognized my graphics card and allowed me to run my monitor at higher resolutions.  Those are the generic drivers I am referring to.  I think, those are vga (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

If you install Nvidia drivers from `.run` files, you will always have to reinstall them after each kernel upgrade.

To install Nvidia drivers a proper way you need to uninstall it first by running

```
sudo sh <nvidia_run_file_name>.run --uninstall
```

from the directory where the driver file is located.

Then you can install nvidia-331 from Ubuntu repositories by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

or install the latest driver from [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Now also 340, 346 and 349 versions are available there.

If you have hybrid grapghics, you need also `nvidia-prime` package.

Comment: Thanks Few more questions.  I thought that proprietary drivers from Nvidia  offer the best performance for my card.  I want to install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.21.run to run with the updated kernel.  I would happily use the method you suggest instead if it will provide comparable performance (watching movies on Netflix and DVDs on a 72" Sony at 1920 x 1080).  Am I correct that I should stick with Nvidia's drivers or will the xorg-edgers version provide comparable performance?  And should I just use the nvidia-352 since I was going to install 64-352.21?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Dr.Eval This is same driver packed the correct way for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Finally tried this.  Specifically ran all of the commands while kernel 3.16.0-41 was loaded (the working kernel).  Everything seemed to execute properly.  But then when I restarted using kernel -43 my display was busted again.  Same problem in -44.  reloading -41 was OK.  Running lshw -c video shows that my driver=NVIDIA so I am stumped again.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this and upgrade you kernel, and enter this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-amd64_ linux-efi
 sudo apt-get install aptitude
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get install -f
 sudo aptitude linux-efi
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Can you give me a quick comment on what each line does and a quick synopsis of how this should fix my problem?

Comment: Upgrade of the kernel file, and if this does not work you could upgrade the gfx driver, and enter this sudo apt-get install nvida-311-updates, and I can not explain every line they just install newer version.